# Spread Date.UTC args issue in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

The first line is giving me a typescript issue:

> Expected 2-7 arguments, but got 0 or more. (2556)

```
const a = Date.UTC(...[2019, 0, 1]);
const b = Date.UTC.apply(Date, [2019, 0, 1]);
```

Why is the first line not working in typescript, both of these work in node.

Comment: [Probably relevant.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27888#issuecomment-429548326)

Comment: As @Jeto points out, the issue is [2019,0,1] is not a tuple. This works : `const a = Date.UTC(...[2019, 0, 1] as [number,number,number]);`